# Second form target without JS?

Tags: html, forms

I want a second target for a delete button in a submit form.

```html
<form action="submit.php">
    <input type="Submit" value="Submit (submit.php)">
    <input type="submit" value="Delete (delete.php)">
</form>
```

I recently read somewhere that it's possible with an attribute so no JS would be required.

`formtarget`doesn't do the trick.

All Google finds are JS solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can by using formaction -

Example:

```
<form>
  <input type="submit" formaction="submit.php" value="submit" />
  <input type="submit" formaction="delete.php" value="delete" />
</form>
```

Comment: Ah! No `<form action=""` then :)